# is there any possible way to check the common column values for multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have those three tables as the attachment shows where i want to get all the borrowers who have borrowed all their borrowed books in a single day

[image]

Comment: Yes, a select query. What have you tried yet? It appears very little.

Comment: yes, it has been a while.

Comment: i used this query to get the borrowers who have borrowed books for double times only



Select DISTINCT BookID,BorrowerID
FROM Book_Borrower group by BorrowerID,BookID
having COUNT(BookID) % 2 = 0

Comment: Please avoid using comments to show your code. Instead, edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query:

```
Select DISTINCT BookID,BorrowerID FROM Book_Borrower group by BorrowerID,BookID having COUNT(BookID) % 2 = 0
```

will give you all the books and borrowers who have borrowed a book an even (2, 4, 6, etc.) number of times.

What you want is:

```
SELECT BorrowerID, COUNT(DISTINCT BorrowDate)
FROM Book_Borrower
GROUP BY BorrowerID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT BorrowDate) = 1
```

The query selects the borrowers and counts the different borrowdates, but filters them to only show the results where there is only one borrowdate.